# Retain format "dd/mm/yy" of date scraped from web by VBA Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

I want to scrape date under format of "dd/mm/yy" from web to Excel by VBA Selenium library.

```vb
Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = driver.FindElementById("table-body-scroll").FindElementsByTag("tr").FindElementsByTag("td")(3).Text ' to get the 3rd col
```

The date value on web is formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy". When I scrape to Excel, it turns to "mm/dd/yyyy".

How do I force Excel to understand the date as "dd/mm/yyyy"?

The URL is: https://iboard.ssi.com.vn/bang-gia/chung-quyen

The column that contains the date is the third col named "GDCC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim DateAry() As String
DateAry = Split(driver.FindElementById("table-body-scroll").FindElementsByTag("tr").FindElementsByTag("td")(3).Text, "/")
Range("A1").Value = DateAry(1) & "/" & DateAry(0) & "/" & DateAry(2)
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

or

```
Dim DateAry() As String
DateAry = Split(driver.FindElementById("table-body-scroll").FindElementsByTag("tr").FindElementsByTag("td")(3).Text, "/")
Range("A1").Value = DateAry(1) & "-" & DateAry(0) & "-" & DateAry(2)
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "DD-MM-YYYY"
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not work in this case. For example, "14/12/20", Excel does not consider it as date

Comment: sorry for this confusion. Your code works well after I recheck it. Thank you so much!

Comment: cleaner and faster to use driver.FindElementByCss(".lastTradingDate") to retrieve the first, or FindElementsByCss to retrieve the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this function I wrote. It returns a date object. Handles the year being 4 or 2 numbers long (i.e 2020 or 20). And doesn't care which "-" or "/" separator you use.

```
Function convert_date_to_uk(dte)
Dim days, months, weeks As String

    months = Left(dte, 2)
    If Len(dte) = 10 Then
        years = Right(dte, 4)
    Else
        years = Right(dte, 2)
    End If
    days = Mid(dte, 4, 2)
    
    convert_date_to_uk = DateSerial(years, months, days)
    
End Function
```

Then it can be used as follows with your example

```
Sheets("Sheet1").range("A1").value = convert_date_to_uk(driver.FindElementById("table-body-scroll").FindElementsByTag("tr").FindElementsByTag("td")(3).Text)
```